# Add new objects to the nested array in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an array like this

```
const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState([
{
  title: "Background",
  id: 0,
  items: [],
},
]);


  const [selectedBox, setSelectedBox] = useState(0);
```

I want to add a new object in items field and copy the past ones,

This is what I'm trying

```
setBoxes(prevState => {
  return [
    ...prevState,
    prevState[selectedBox].items: [...prevState[selectedBox].items, {title:"test"}]      
  ]
})
```

Thanks a lot, have a nice day

Comment: is state supposed to be an array? or is that just the boxes array?

Comment: The field items is supposed to be an array with objects

Comment: why not just use `.push` ?

Comment: I assume you utilize index with this 'prevState[selectedBox]' If so, before returning you can find and change the object you want to change and then plug in the return. Meaning that you find the item, make the changes and then compose your state (+return)

Comment: .push will save on performance by `not` copying all the items

Comment: @SoluableNonagon push is working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you are trying to do exactly due to the lack of information but you can try something like this:

```
setBoxes(prevState => {
  const newBoxes = {
    ...prevState,
  };
  newBoxes[selectedBox].items = [
    ...newBoxes[selectedBox].items,
    { title: 'test' },
  ];
  return newBoxes;
})
```

Comment: I want to add a new object on box[selectedItem].items, cuz this will be soon dynamic and could have more than one box